# Is it possible to change the black 'background color' of iOS apps?

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a app with a cube animation. There will appear a black background when I swipe to another viewcontroller. Is there any solution for this?
[image]

**More advanced**

Thanks for the solution! I dont know if it is possible, but does anyone know if you can put something like a svg image on the window background?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Objective-C**

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor]; // customize ur self

}
```

**Swift**

```
  func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {

  self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor() // customize ur self

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change background colour of window in AppDelegate

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appDelegate.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```